# Scrapy Not Following the Link to Next Page Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape Booking.Com for information like tags, reviews, etc. The spider crawls the information as I want but when I add the code to crawl next page, it doesn't even crawl the first page.I am familiar with Link Extractors but I don't know how to provide the value for parameters.For Example, Idk what how do I select what arguments to provide the parameters i.e. allow, restrict. Please tell me what's wrong with the code and also how to put arguments.Help will be much appreciated. Thanks! in anticipation. Here's the code

```
import scrapy
import urllib
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from quo.items import QuoItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes1'
    allowed_domains=['booking.com']


    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.booking.com/hotel/us/jolly-madison-towers.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaLUBiAEBmAExwgEKd2luZG93cyAxMMgBDNgBA-gBAfgBApICAXmoAgM;sid=a4397d59763c8a4caec92e6242e50b46;checkin=2017-07-05;checkout=2017-07-06;ucfs=1;soh=1;highlighted_blocks=;all_sr_blocks=;room1=A%2CA;soldout=0%2C0;hpos=2;dest_type=city;dest_id=20088325;srfid=4cc7afd646ecfd94fcc083a01cd786310c221d4eX2;from=searchresults;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', self.parse)
    rules = (

    )

    def parse(self, response):
         reviewsurl = response.xpath('//a[@class="show_all_reviews_btn"]/@href')
         url = response.urljoin(reviewsurl[0].extract())
         self.pageNumber=1
         yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_content)


    def parse_content(self, response):
        item=QuoItem()
        user_rating=response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="reviewRating"]/meta[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content').extract()
        if user_rating:
                item['User_Rating']=user_rating
        title=response.xpath('//*[@class="review_item_header_content_container"]/a/span[@itemprop="name"]').extract()
        if title:
           item['Title']=title
        rev_positive=response.xpath('//p[@class="review_pos"]/span[@itemprop="reviewBody"]/text()').extract()
        if rev_positive:
                item['rev_positive']=rev_positive
        rev_negative=response.xpath('//p[@class="review_neg"]/span[@itemprop="reviewBody"]/text()').extract()
        if rev_positive:
                item['rev_negative']=rev_negative
                return item

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@id="review_next_page_link"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_content)
```

Here is the output when I run this spider[Output when I add next_page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw4ZU.png)
As you can see in the log, the spider does go to the review page but crawls nothing. Here's the output when I remove the next_page code. It goes to the review page and do as it is told.[Output when I remove the next_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk5LV.png)

Comment: You pasted the same console log output twice (same start time and end time, same number of requests)

Comment: I haven't checked your XPaths, but what happens if you change `return item` with `yield item`? You should either only use `yield` or return a list of item/requests.